# TextBlock with back button

Tags: c#, uwp, header, back-button

I am trying to create a header that has a backbutton for my application's splitview.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Header with button]

I have tried putting an appbutton in my stack panel, but it seems to push my textblock down. 
Here's my code:

`

```
<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource CitiKioskBackgroundBrush}" Height="100">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Margin=" 30 40 0 0"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" 
               Foreground="White" FontSize="30px" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
               Margin=" 0 40 0 0"  >
        CitiKiosk Settings
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

`

[image: Header without title]

Comment: have you tried changing the     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  ?

Comment: I think you can add TextBlock in AppBarButton .

Comment: For this type of thing.. well for almost all type of thing, and just to be sure that I can control the layout I use the Grid component rather than StackPanel, also, scales better. I think that if you put this in a grid with one row, and two columns, one for the image, one for the text, will be easy to control.. but there are multiple solutions for this. Hope it helps.

Comment: I write it in AppBarButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do it is use Label , please see the code below.

```
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Margin=" 30 40 0 0" Label=" CitiKiosk Settings">
```

But it's seen not what you want.

[image]

For make the AppBarButton like this image, that you should change it's style.

[image]

The code below is the style and you can write it in Page.Resources

```
    <Style TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root"
                          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                          MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode" >
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                              Height="20"
                                              Margin="0,0,0,4"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       FontSize="30"
                                       FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                       TextAlignment="Center"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Margin="10,0,0,6"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then you can write the AppBarButton with the style.

```
    <AppBarButton Width="300" Icon="Back" Margin="30 0 0 0" Label="CitiKiosk Settings" />
```

The UI is like this image.

[image]

I think you can change the icon and the background. And if you want to change the Foreground that you should only set the Foreground in AppBarButton.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It works! Really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you only need to add a `Orientation="Horizontal"` property in your StackPanel.

That is:

```
<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource CitiKioskBackgroundBrush}"
            Height="100" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Margin=" 30 40 0 0"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" 
               Foreground="White" FontSize="30px" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
               Margin=" 0 40 0 0"  >
        CitiKiosk Settings
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```